# ansible The connection's stdin object is deprecated

Tags: ansible

Since ansible [core 2.15.3] update I am getting the following message while using: ansible.posix.synchronize

`[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The connection's stdin object is deprecated. Call display.prompt_until(msg) instead. This feature will be removed in version 2.19. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.`

Anyone got an idea how to get rid of it?

This is the snychronize part:

```
 - ansible.posix.synchronize:
        src: x
        dest: x
        times: false
        rsync_opts:
          - "--no-motd"
```

Comment: Can you share your `ansible.cfg` file, the whole playbook as well the command line which was used to call it? Just like to note that the message comes from the [`plugins/connection/__init__.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/__init__.py#L108) and not from the `synchronize` module.

Comment: The problem is definitely in the `synchronize` module. There's an [open PR](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix/pull/421) which got a bit of attention again yesterday and should hopefully make it to the next release.

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation warning can be ignored since that object isn't used for anything in Ansible itself. As Zeitounator stated, there's a pull request to remove the stdin object from the synchronize module. It is not utilized in the module and will simply be removed in a future release.

Alternatively, you can disable deprecation warnings by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.

I'm not certain that's what you meant by "how to get rid of it?" but that's all you can do for now.